# Proving an optimization problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

I have the following problem I would need help with :) :

Given $N$ positive values $u_n$, where $n=1, ..., N$, the problem is to determine the unknown parameters $w_n$ to maximize the criterion function:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N u_n\log w_n$$

under the constraints $w_n > 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N w_n = 1$. Prove that the optimal parameters have a closed form solution:

$$w_n = \frac{u_n}{\sum_{n=1}^N u_n}\;\; \text{for}\;\;n=1, ..., N $$

How should I approach this problem? :)
Thnx for any help :)

Comment: Did you try using Lagrange multipliers ?

Comment: No, thnx for the advice :)

Comment: I didn't know this property of entropy. Could you tell me where you got it from?

Comment: @fabee Yes I can :) Here is my reference: http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0131478249/samplechapter/0131478249_ch03.pdf page 33/35 problem 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While thinking about whether I know that property of entropy, I found an easy solution.

First of all, 
$$\mbox{argmax}_w \sum_i u_i \log(w_i) = \mbox{argmin}_w -\sum_i \frac{u_i}{\overline{u}} \log(w_i)$$
with $\overline{u}=\sum_i u_i$.

Now, let $z_i = \frac{u_i}{\overline{u}}$, then
$$-\sum_i z_i \log(w_i) = -\sum_i z_i \log\left(w_i\frac{z_i}{z_i}\right)=-\sum_i z_i \log\left(z_i\right) + \sum_i z_i \log\left(\frac{z_i}{w_i}\right).$$

The term $\sum_i z_i \log\left(\frac{z_i}{w_i}\right)$ is the Kullback-Leibler divergence between the discrete distribution $z_i$ and $w_i$ which can be shown to be always positive (just check Wikipedia). It is zero iff $z_i=w_i$. Therefore, your function is optimized if $z_i=w_i$.